# Install resources in a folder (img, icons) in Inno Setup

Tags: qt, inno-setup

Does anyone know how to reference a folder (`img`, `icons`, ...) as resources in Inno Setup? My problem is when I install my application in another computer, the application doesn't know the path of my images. For example, a button with icon is shown without its icon.

Comment: Why don't you embed the resources in a .qrc file?

Comment: My resources are indeed inside a qrc file  but when i generate a setup with inno setup and i install my app in another PC  my application can't find the  resources for exemple - a button is shown with out its icon. what should i do? should insert qrc file in setup?

Answer (score 2):

Install the resources to the same relative paths as you have them, when developing the application.

I.e. if you have file `img/ico_charger.ico`, install it like:

```
[Files]
Source: "c:\myproject\img\ico_charger.ico"; DestDir: "{app}/img"
```

Or you can install all files in the `img` folder at once:

```
[Files]
Source: "c:\myproject\img\*"; DestDir: "{app}/img"
```

For details see a documentation for the [`[Files]` section](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection).

---

And of course make sure your application uses relative paths when accessing the resources.